# How to defer passing of Ajax data to child components?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm building a simple to-do app with Vue 2.0 using built-in parent-child communication. The parent element that is directly attached to the Vue instance (`new Vue({...}`) is as follows:

```
<!-- Tasks.vue -->
<template>
    <div>
        <create-task-form></create-task-form>

        <task-list :tasks="tasks"></task-list>

        <task-list :tasks="incompleteTasks"></task-list>

        <task-list :tasks="completeTasks"></task-list>
</template>
<script>
    import CreateTaskForm from './CreateTaskForm.vue';
    import TaskList from './TaskList.vue';

    export default {
        components: { CreateTaskForm, TaskList },
        data() { return { tasks: [] }; },

        created() { // Ajax call happens here...
            axios.get('/api/v1/tasks')
                .then(response => {
                    this.tasks = response.data;
                    console.log(this.tasks); // THIS IS LOGGED LAST
                });
        },
        computed: {
            completeTasks() {
                return this.tasks.filter(task => task.complete);
            },
            incompleteTasks() {
                return this.tasks.filter(task => task.complete);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The idea is that `<tasks></tasks>` will display a form to create a new task, as well 3 lists - all tasks, incomplete, and complete tasks. Each list is the same component:

```
<!-- TaskList.vue -->
<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="task in taskList">
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="task.complete"> {{ task.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() { return { taskList: [] }; },
        props: ['tasks'],

        mounted() {
            this.taskList = this.tasks;
            console.log(this.tasks); // THIS IS LOGGED FIRST
        }
    }
</script>
```

### Problem

As you can see, I am trying to pass data from `<tasks>` to each of the 3 `<task-lists>`, using dynamic `:tasks` property:

```
<task-list :tasks="tasks"></task-list>

<task-list :tasks="incompleteTasks"></task-list>

<task-list :tasks="completeTasks"></task-list>
```

*Note*, I am not using shared (global) state, because each list needs a **different** portion of data, even though these portions of data belong to the same store. But the problem is that `:tasks` are assigned an empty array **before** the Ajax call happens; and as I am guessing, props are immutable, hence `tasks` in the child `<task-list>` are never updated when data is fetched in the parent `<tasks>`. In fact, `<task-list>` is created first (see the log), and **only then** the data is fetched using Ajax.

### Questions

- How do I defer the passing of data from `<tasks>` to my `<task-list>`s? How do I make sure that all components refer to the single source of truth that's updated dynamically?
- Is there a way to solve this parent-child communication problem with "vanilla" Vue.js? Or do I need to use Vuex or something similar?
- Am I right in using properties to pass data to children? Or should I use shared store in a global variable?

Comment: Using a shared global store is not the problem here. As @wostex answered mounted() is called only once. So for taskList property to be updated you should use computed properties. And if you consider using global store vuex would best solve your purpose. You can find an example that relates to you here( https://coligo.io/learn-vuex-by-building-notes-app/ )

Comment: @user7814783 The problem I had with the global store (and by that I mean just a [global var declared right before the parent](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/24) `<tasks>` component) is that each child `<task-list>` component needs it own version of the data (all, incomplete, and complete tasks). But it's still the same component! (`<task-list>`) So I couldn't figure out how to pass different portions of data from the same store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here: `mounted() { this.taskList = this.tasks; ...}` inside `TaskList.vue` as `taskList` property is updated only on `mounted` event.

There's a trivial solution in Vue: you should make `taskList` a `computed property` which depends on props, so that when parent data changes your computed property gets updated:

```
props: ['tasks'],
computed: {
  taskList: function() {
    return this.tasks;
  }
}
```

Don't forget to remove `taskList` from `data` block.

Also, I would rewrite `v-model="task.complete"` into `@change="$emit('something', task.id)"` to inform a parent component that status has changed (and listen to ). Otherwise parent will never know the box is checked. You can then listen for this event on parent component to change tasks status accordingly. More reading: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events

Comment: Thanks a lot! On your last comment about emitting an event, I noticed that when `task.complete` or `task.name` changes by the means of `v-model`, the changes in data are reflected in sibling components, hence the parent `<tasks>` is notified too. Is there a way to capture these data changes, so I could send a `patch` request to the server whenever needed? (Using event emissions, I would have to pass the event from one component to another, potentially in a long chain of nodes)

Comment: You can pass any data with your event `$emit('myevent', data)`, for example a full object. In your parent component when you listen to this event you have access to this data in `$event` argument: `@myevent="handleEvent($event)"`, then your method will look like `handleEvent(event) { this.newData = event}` - the data you sent. So, you can send changed `task` object and in parent component find task by id and compare what've changed. If there are changes - perform your path or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use **watch** property of vue instance

```
watch:{
   tasks(newVal){
        this.taskList = newVal;
      //do something
   }
}
```